# Custom Class for Jasper report

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have 2 custom classes I want to use in my Jasper report.
I have followed this suggestion: [Custom Class for JasperReports field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900793/custom-class-for-jasperreports-field)
How ever I can't get IReport to compile the report.

Compile result:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRValidationException: Report design not valid :
1. java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Will not load classes from default package (Client)      
2. java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Will not load classes from default package (User)     
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractCompiler.verifyDesign(JRAbstractCompiler.java:271) 
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractCompiler.compileReport(JRAbstractCompiler.java:153)     
at com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.compiler.IReportCompiler.run(IReportCompiler.java:512)     
at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:572)     
at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:997)
```

The jrxml file:
https://gist.github.com/4285142

I am parsing another class, which holds an object of theese 2 classes:

User class:

```
public class User
{
    int _userId;
    UserPermission _userPermission;
    String _firstName;
    String _lastName;
    String _userName;
    String _userPassword;
    String _saltValue;
    Date _creationDate;
    Date _editedDate;

    //get&setters
}
```

Client class:

```
public class Client 
{
     int _clientId;
     String _name;
     String _address;
     City _city;
     long _phoneNo;
     String _eMail;
     Date _creationDate;
     Date _editedDate;

     //get&setters
}
```

Comment: Have you tried moving these classes to a proper package? The error seems to suggest that it can't use classes from the default package (i.e. no package)

Comment: @Guillaume I might need to import the classes somehow. I just don't know how to do it.

Comment: You can define imports in the .jrxml file, actually looking at your design you're already importing models.Client and models.User, maybe you could try importing models.* instead?

Comment: @Guillaume Just trying changing the import to "models.*", still the same compile error.
My folder structure is /appName/src/, where the report is located in src and the package/folder models aswell (/appName/src/models/)

Comment: Are you trying to compile from iReport? If so you might need to add your compiled classes folder to iReport's classpath. Go to Tools -> Options -> iReport -> Classpath

Comment: @Guillaume I didn't work either :(
Custom classes seems to complicated. I wrote a java wrapper class which I parse to the JRBeanCollectionDatasource instead. It works now, and I'm able to generate the pdf :)